# Compiler optimization or my misunderstanding

Tags: c++, oop, g++, copy-constructor, compiler-optimization

Recently I was testing some C++ deep and dark corners and I got confused about one subtle point. My test is so simple actually:

```
// problem 1
// no any constructor call, g++ acts as a function declaration to the (howmany())
// g++ turns (howmany()) into (howmany(*)()) 
howmany t(howmany());

// problem 2
// only one constructor call
howmany t = howmany();
```

My expectation from above line was; first `howmany()` constructor call will produce one temporary object and then compiler will use that temporary object with copy-constructor in order to instantiate **t**. However, output of compiler really confused me because output shows only one constructor call. My friends mentioned me about compiler pass-by-value optimization but we are not sure about it. I want to learn what does happen here ?

Output of problem 2 is below. problem 1 is completely beyond object instantiation because compiler behaves it as a function pointer declaration.

```
howmany()
~howmany()
```

My test class is:

```
class howmany {
    public:
        howmany() {
            out << "howmany()" << endl;
        }
        howmany(int i) {
            out << "howmany(i)" << endl;
        }
        howmany(const howmany& refhm) {
            out << "howmany(howmany&)" << endl;
        }
        howmany& operator=(const howmany& refhm) {
            out << "operator=" << endl;
        }
        ~howmany() {
            out << "~howmany()" << endl;
        }
        void print1() {
            cout << "print1()" << endl;
        }
        void print2() {
            cout << "print2()" << endl;
        }
};
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the [most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) here:

```
howmany t( howmany() );
```

In order to fix this you need to add an extra set of parens:

```
howmany t( (howmany()) );
           ^         ^
```

`clang` is very helpful here and warns you:

```
warning: parentheses were disambiguated as a function declaration [-Wvexing-parse]
howmany t( howmany() );
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:31:12: note: add a pair of parentheses to declare a variable
howmany t( howmany() );
          ^
          (        )
```

The other way to fix this is to use *C++11* [uniform initialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Uniform_initialization) syntax:

```
howmany t{ howmany{} };
         ^        ^^ ^
```

**Update**

To address part `2` which you added to the question the [draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) allows for omission of the copy/move construction in some cases. We can see this from section `12.8` *Copying and moving class objects* paragraph *31* which says:

> When certain criteria are met, an implementation is allowed to omit the copy/move construction of a class object, even if the constructor selected for the copy/move operation and/or the destructor for the object have side effects. In such cases, the implementation treats the source and target of the omitted copy/move operation as simply two different ways of referring to the same object, and the destruction of that object occurs at the later of the times when the two objects would have been destroyed without the optimization.122 This elision of copy/move operations, called copy elision, is permitted in the following circumstances

and includes the following bullet:

> when a temporary class object that has not been bound to a reference (12.2) would be copied/moved to a class object with the same cv-unqualified type, the copy/move operation can be omitted by constructing the temporary object directly into the target of the omitted copy/move

Comment: thank you, it was one of my problem :) but could you please look to my post again because i updated it with another problem

Comment: @MuratKarakuş wait, you changed the question, now future readers will be confused. Clarifications should be added as edits to the end of your question or should be made as comments to answers or the the question.

Comment: @MuratKarakuş: Edits are there to improve the question, not to change it into something different. At this point I fell like downvoting Shafik just because this answer is unrelated to the question above!!!!

Comment: @MuratKarakuş, please post another question and rollback your edit.

Comment: Sorry guys, I forgot it, now i revised in order to make it more clear for everybody.

Comment: actually i updated it in order to fit all answers if you still think i should remove it, it is ok for me but i think last version covers your answer and i really appreciate it.

Comment: @MuratKarakuş updated to reflect question 2 as well.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour you explained both questions clearly and concisely. I accepted it. Actually i just closed optimizations of compiler so i got what i want but your explanation made my mind more clear. thank you very much.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I appreciate you not downvoting my answer.

Comment: @MuratKarakuş no problem, it worked out in the end and I am happy my answer helped.

Comment: The example does not really apply to this case, the case in the question falls on the third bullet: *when a temporary class object that has not been bound to a reference (12.2) would be copied/moved
to a class object with the same cv-unqualified type, the copy/move operation can be omitted by constructing the temporary object directly into the target of the omitted copy/move* The example is that of a function call, where there are conceptually more copies. Still the main point holds.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas yeah, you are correct the third bullet is indeed sufficient on it's own without the example. Let me replace it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is one of the optimization compiler may do.
The compiler is allowed to eliminate temporary object creation even if copy constructor has side effects!

Comment: thank you :) do you have any suggestion for c++ interview in the terms of this kind of questions because i dont know how to react this. For instance; they can ask how many object is created or which constructors are called etc ... ? It looks like answer is depend on the compiler

Comment: Herb Sutter's Guru of the week has a nice collection of this sort of questions. (http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/)

Answer (score 1):

After getting clues from above answers I found real problem. In my case, especially problem 2, compiler eliminates the copy construction process because return value of  **howmany() constructor call** is completely **same to the howmany t object**, for that reason compiler just **eliminates copy-construction** process in order to **make optimization**.  More detail of this problem is covered in wikipedia, please look to there.[Return value optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization)

**-fno-elide-constructors** is one of g++ flags which is responsible from disabling the optimizations. In cmake we just need to set it.

`set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-fno-elide-constructors")`

After disabling optimizations, the output of program turned what i was expecting.

```
howmany()
howmany(howmany&)
~howmany()
~howmany()
```

Thanks :)