# Interesting behaviour when calling constructor in templated constructor

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, compiler-errors

I just created a really little project I thought I could do in no time (it's about basic delegates) when I came across an interesting compiler bug that I couldn't track down. Here is the simplified version of the code:

```
class NoComp {
};

class Comp {
    bool operator==(const Comp& other)
    { std::cout << "Working!" << std::endl; return true;}
};

struct Test {
    template<typename T>
    Test(T&& obj) {}
    bool operator==(const Test& other);
};
int main()
{
    Test a(Comp());
    Test b(NoComp());
    a.operator ==(b);
}
```

This produces the following compiler error when compiled with `g++ version 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-7) (GCC)` [found here](http://goo.gl/hRFYyn):

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':                                    
main.cpp:22:13: error: request for member 'operator==' in 'a', which is
 of non-class type 'Test(Comp (*)())'                                  
  a.operator ==(b);
```

I can't figure out what that error means and why it even exists. What happens there, is it a bug or covered by the standard? How can I dodge that, if I can?

Comment: Most vexing parse...

Comment: Yep - you're declaring a type

Comment: ... a function, rather

Comment: There is a similar question: [Compiler optimization or my misunderstanding](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20665104/1708801). Note, as I demonstrated in my answer there `clang` would have given you a very helpful warning, it is often helpful to try examples in more than one compiler.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Test a(Comp());
Test b(NoComp());
```

This declares two functions called `a` and `b`. The first one has one parameter of type `Comp(*)()` and a return type of `Test`, and the second one takes a `NoComp(*)()` and also returns a `Test`. `Comp()` is a function type and, as all parameters of function type, adjusted to a pointer-to-function type. Same goes for `NoComp()`.

Use double parentheses:

```
Test a((Comp()));
Test b((NoComp()));
```

Or list-initialization as of C++11.

Answer (score 3):

You have what is called the [most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

The lines

```
Test a(Comp());
Test b(NoComp());
```

do not declare variables, but two functions `a` and `b`, taking a pointer-to-function that returs `Comp` (`NoComp`) and takes no parameters.

If you have access to C++11, use the list-initialization, i.e.

```
Test a{Comp()};
Test b{NoComp()};
```

or if you don't, use double parenthesis

```
Test a((Comp()));
Test b((NoComp()));
```

Comment: I never saw the double parenthesis before. Is there any downside to it? (apart from taking up space?). If I just mechanically use `((` to wrap around every call to a constructor, will it always work? e.g. `X * xp = new X(( Comp(()), NoComp(()) ))` ?